# Trying to loop through linq query results and display in js code

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, linq-to-sql

I am using a google maps api to display locations on a web page. I have gotten this working using static locations as seen in the js code below. I have put the exact locations into a sql table and instead would like to display the locations by using the table instead of the hard coded locations. Basically i want to loop through my linq result and show this in the javascript code. So var locations = (my result set) I know my code is pretty far off but thought it would help show what i am trying to accomplish. ANy help would be appreciated! Thanks

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (var db = new DataClasses1DataContext())
        {
            var place = (from p in db.Coordinates
                         select new {locName = p.LocationName, 
                             Coord1 = p.Coordinate1,  
                             Coord2 = p.Coordinate2}).ToList();

            //List<string> listPlaces = new List<string>();

            foreach (var result in place)
            {
                string name = place.locName;
                bool Coordinate1 = place.Coord1;
                bool Coordinate2 = place.Coord2;
            }
        }
    }

    <script type="text/javascript">
    var locations =
        ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856],
        ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052],
        ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507],
        ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187],
        ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302]
    ];
```

Edit: I did get it to work with the first record in the table correctly but the end result needs to be all rows.

C#:
    var place = (from p in db.Coordinates
        where p.LocationName == "Adam"
        select p).FirstOrDefault();
        name = place.LocationName;
        coord1 = place.Coordinate1.Value;
        coord2 = place.Coordinate2.Value;

Javascript:
    var name2 = "<%=name%>";
    var coordinate1 = "<%=coord1%>";
    var coordinate2 = "<%=coord2%>";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a number of options: Build it as a string, Use a JsonSeralizer on your object, AJAX call to a method to get the JSON, many others...

To me building it as a string is the simple and easy way (for an object of this complexity and size):

On aspx page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var locations = <asp:literal id="locations" runat="server" />;
</script>
```

Code:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
bool isFirst = true;
foreach (var result in place)
{
    if (!isFirst)
    {
        sb.Append(",");
    }
    isFirst = false;

    //Add the item data
    sb.AppendFormat("['{0}', {1}, {2}]", result.locName, result.Coord1, result.Coord2);
}
locations.Text = sb.ToString();
```

You could also use `Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock` to add the script to the page in a more dynamic way.

Comment: Interesting. I tried this and it all mostly makes sense but locations does not exist in its current context in the c# code. How do i declare it?  Edit: actually it compiles now but the map doesnt load.

Comment: The original answer I forgot to have `runat="server"` so either that was missing or maybe the aspx page was cached somehow...  1. Are there any javascript errors? 2. If you View Source in your browser, does the locations variable look like it was generated correctly?

Comment: No js errors but it looks to be that line because it will load if i comment it out. The c# locations string value is correctly populated with all 5 locations

Comment: I'd guess some syntax problem.  Your question had it end with `];`  Was this part of a larger javascript object? If so you might not want the `;` after the `literal`  Or make sure the brackets are all matching, and that it doesn't need curly brackets around it or anything?

Comment: No what you see of lacocations is the whole object. I did try adding brackets like the original static data with no luck

Comment: and used a c# variable in js instead var locations = [<%=locations%>];